Can I Customize the Drag-and-Drop Installation Screen for macOS in an Electron App?
I'm building an Electron app and packaging it for macOS. By default, the macOS installation process shows the standard drag-and-drop screen where users drag the app icon into the Applications folder.
I would like to know:

Is it possible to customize this drag-and-drop screen? For example, can I modify its appearance, add animations, or change the background?
Can I add additional functionality, like showing a confirmation screen or an animation after the user completes the drag-and-drop action?

If the default macOS behavior cannot be modified directly, are there any alternative tools or workflows I can use to achieve a more branded installation experience?
I’ve been able to make basic customizations, such as changing the icon, destination folder, and background image. However, I’d like to go further and:
1.Modify the drag-and-drop screen itself (e.g., adding animations or changing the layout).
2. Add a screen or some functionality to indicate installation is complete once the user drags the app to the destination.
